# Foreach with multiple list items in unordered list inside a div based on start letter of page_title

Tags: php, html, loops, foreach

It was very hard to even explain it in a short title but I did my best.

I have a foreach loop that is working fine but the way it should display the results is driving me crazy.

In the loop I check if a page title starts with a certain letter. If so I start a new DIV for this certain letter. This with every letter of the alpabet.

Only the opening `<div>` tag, `<ul>` tag etc. should be used once inside the loop. Same for the closing tags. Only the `<li>` items should be repeated.

I got that working too but it does not display the way I want and I dont know what I'm doing wrong at this moment.

It displays like this:

```
<div class="l-col-12">
    <div class="widget toggle-widget">
        <header>
            <h3 class="widget-title" id="letter-category-N">N</h3>
        </header>
        <div class="widget-content" style="display: block;">
            <ul>

                <li> <a href="#">Nog een provider</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <li> <a href="#">Neostrada</a></li> <!-- This li is outside the div -->
</div>
```

But it should be like this:

```
<div class="l-col-12">
    <div class="widget toggle-widget">
        <header>
            <h3 class="widget-title" id="letter-category-N">N</h3>
        </header>
        <div class="widget-content" style="display: block;">
            <ul>

                <li> <a href="#">Nog een provider</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#">Neostrada</a></li> <!-- Should be here -->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I had this problem before and as I can remember I did the same then as I am doing now but no luck this time.

**This is the code doing it:**

```
<div class="l-col-12">
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 
    'post_type'     => array( 'page' ),
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'is_featured' => array(
            'key' => 'soort_abonnement',
            'value' => '',
            'compare' => 'NOT IN'
        )),
    );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
$letter_A_start = false;
$letter_N_start = false;
?>
<?php
foreach ( $myposts as $post ){
    setup_postdata( $post ); 
        $pagina_titel_bedrijf = get_the_title();
                if($pagina_titel_bedrijf[0] == "A" && !$letter_A_start){ ?>
                <div class="widget toggle-widget">
                    <header>
                        <h3 class="widget-title" id="letter-category-A">A</h3>
                    </header>
                    <div class="widget-content" style="display: block;">
                        <ul>
                            <?php $letter_A_start = true; ?>                         
                            <li> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
                            <?php if($letter_A_start == true){?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php } else {} }?>


                <?php if($pagina_titel_bedrijf[0] == "N") { ?>
                <?php if($pagina_titel_bedrijf[0] == "N" && !$letter_N_start){?>
                <div class="widget toggle-widget">
                    <header>
                        <h3 class="widget-title" id="letter-category-N">N</h3>
                    </header>
                    <div class="widget-content" style="display: block;">
                        <ul>
                            <?php $letter_N_start = true;} ?>                        
                            <li> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
                            <?php if($letter_N_start == true){?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php } else {} } ?>
<?php } ?>          
<?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
            </div>
```

Comment: `<?php $letter_A_start = true; ?>` You are explicitly setting these variables to `true` right before you check them. So they're always going to be `true` and the following code (the closing tags) will always run.

Comment: @mickmackusa The value is checked in two different places. I'm talking about where it is checked before displaying the closing tags, which is the issue OP is having.

Comment: You should probably start by making sure your posts are actually sorted by title, because right now I can’t see you doing that anywhere - and with unsorted data this kind of “grouping” would not be possible to achieve in a single loop over the data to begin with.

Comment: Plus, a _proper_ description of what you want to achieve here would not go amiss either. Do you only have records with titles starting with either A or N? Or are there others, but you want to output only those? Or is this supposed to break records into two lists, A-M and N-Z, effectively?

Comment: @mickmackusa Yes, this is only the letter N but as I said. It is for the whole alphabet. So ABCDE.... and if no starting letter is found no DIV is opened at all. Patrick Q I'm not a PHP guru, just trying stuff and I thought that because the second check (for closing) is after the LI it was no problem. But you guys are saying with the current code it aint going to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested Code:

```
$listitems = [];
foreach ( $myposts as $post ){
    setup_postdata( $post ); 
    if (strlen($title = get_the_title())) {
        $listitems[strtoupper($title[0])][] = '<li> <a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . $title . '</a></li>';
    }
}

foreach ($listitems as $letter => $items) {
    echo '<div class="widget toggle-widget">';
        echo '<header>';
            echo "<h3 class=\"widget-title\" id=\"letter-category-{$letter}\">{$letter}</h3>";
        echo '</header>';
        echo '<div class="widget-content" style="display: block;">';
            echo '<ul class="webhosters-list">';
                echo implode($items);
            echo '</ul>';
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

This should DRY-out your code block and make everything easier to manage.

Iterate your posts and store each list item string in a multi-dimensional array for future implosion inside your greater div block.

The second foreach loop will simply not create any div block unless there are `<li>` tags to display.

I am calling `strtoupper()` on the first character of the title when it is used as a key in the `$listitems` array, so that everything is uniform.  If this is not necessary, you can remove that part.

Comment: I need to fix a couple things.  Thanks.

Comment: thanks a lot. I wil try this. This is a way cleaner aproach

Comment: I tried your code and almost working:) The way in which the code is now being built is good. Only he puts the list items not in the unordered list but somewhere above the DIV.

Comment: for some reason it only displays the list-items with empty a-tags. The permalink and title are there but not on the right place. Code seems good to me but title and permalink are just beneath '<div class="l-col-12">' as plain text. You got eny idea?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it working.  the_permalink() and the_title() are not working in that way.

Comment: (I just got out of bed) Yes, I now realize that those functions print to screen.  What was your adjustment?  (I don't use wordpress ...this is wordpress right?)

Comment: Better late then never, I saved the get_title and get_permalink inside a variable:  $pagina_title = get_the_title();
$pagina_link = get_permalink(); Ohw and Yes, it is WordPress. After saving and using variables instead of get_the_title it works:)

Comment: I love late versus never.  I have adjusted my snippet to hopefully make it correct/functional.